# Integration by Parts - Relativistic Energy

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I was trying to derive the kinetic energy for a relativistic particle, and I came across this article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_energy#Relativistic_kinetic_energy_of_rigid_bodies. I was able to follow it for a while, then I became quite stuck on this step, noting that $ \vec p = \gamma m\vec v $ how does:

$$ \int \vec v \cdot d\vec p  = m \gamma \vec v \cdot \vec v  - \int \vec v \cdot d\vec v $$

By my calculations, I think it should be:

$$ \int \vec v \cdot d\vec p  =  m \gamma \vec v \cdot \vec v  -\int m\gamma \vec v \cdot d(\gamma m \vec v) $$

I feel as though I am missing something pretty big here. Can anybody point out the mistake in my working?

Thanks Guys!

Comment: I'm not sure about your work, but neither equation looks completely right just by looking at the units. Your integral has two factors of mass, so you're adding something with units of mass to units of mass squared.

Comment: There was a silly mistake on my part, I transcribed incorrectly from Wikipedia. Worse than that, I differentiated the v in terms of v, rather than doing it in terms of p.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote:

$$ \int \vec v \cdot d\vec p  = m \gamma \vec v \cdot \vec v  - \int \vec v \cdot d\vec v $$

You transcribed that wrong from Wiki. It should be:

$$ \int \vec v \cdot d\vec p  = m \gamma \vec v \cdot \vec v  -  \int m \gamma\vec v \cdot d\vec v $$

which is the correct form.

To see why, consider this formulation of integration by parts:

$$\int udw + \int wdu = uw$$

and now put $u = \vec v$ and $w = m \gamma \vec v$ and use dot products instead of just multiplication by the element of integration. Remember that the dot product is commutative.

Comment: Awesome! Thats perfect!

My only other problem is, I used the integral of $I = \int 1 \cdot \vec v dp$ to expand this. So I got $I = pv-\int p dp$. Sorry about the sloppy notation, but why does that come out wrong? Thanks again :)

Comment: Okay, I know what I did wrong! Rookie mistake!!! I accidentally differentiated v in terms of v, instead of p. Thanks again Deepak :)! You were a huge help.